# Is It Possible To Join Table In Different Server and Database

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, web-applications, microservices

i don't have any problem when joining table on different database in same server, but when the database is separate let say database A on server A and database B on server B how can i join table from server A and database A to table in server B and database B? 
If is possible, how? And if not, what is the best method for me to do? im using php and mysql for my database.
thanks...

Comment: how about different server? i don't have any problem on same server.. the problem when database A on server A and database B on server B

Comment: 1 = Yes..., 2) depends on the other database server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server this one stands to be a duplicate. Edit: and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752477/joining-tables-from-different-servers - You could have Google'd this, if you haven't.

Comment: Any other recommendations besides FEDERATED ENGINE ?